# Nginx with multiple Jenkins Instance

Tags: docker, nginx, jenkins

I've multiple jenkins instances for manage the different pipelines . 
For example pre-prod, staging or etc.

So that I wanna acces these Jenkins services via Nginx. I wanna use the multiple Jenkins instances .

When I write a nginx configuration files . Shown as below.

```
server{
listen      80;
location ^~ /pre-prod/ {
    proxy_pass  http://pre-prod-instance:8080/machine_ID/;

    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
 }


server{
listen      80;
location ^~ /staging/ {
    proxy_pass  http://staging-instance:8080/machine_ID/;

    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
 }
```

I can access the pre-prod instance bu when I request to the staging server I'm getting 404 status code from Nginx .

Notice: These files at /etc/conf.d/ directory.

Comment: If you are using docker for this use https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy it worked great for me.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion I will try it to handling multiple vhosts in docker images

Answer (score 0):

we are using `upstream`

for instance

```
upstream svc {
  server svc:8040;
}
```

and under server

```
 location /path {
  proxy_set_header Host svc;
  proxy_pass  http://svc/;
 }
```

Comment: I wanna discover the services via sub directory in actually.